# MySQL - Calculating days ago

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

Is there a way to work out the time since a timestamp on a record purely using a MySQL query? So basically something like: `TIMESINCE(record.timeupdated) as timeSinceUpdaye` I'm passing the result straight to encodeJson() so don't what to do the calculation in PHP. Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select 
    timestampdiff(SECOND, now(), record.timeupdated) as timeSinceUpdate 
from record;
```

Will return the number of seconds since the last update.

The legal values for `unit` are as follows: MICROSECOND (microseconds), SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, QUARTER, or YEAR. See [`timestampdiff(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) for details.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thank you!